# Convert local path URI to File or Blob

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a copy and paste feature for my website, so here is my problem. When i copy an image directly from a webpage it works as it should (the first if statement on the code), but if i am trying to copy a image from my own computer a i get a local path (like the one in the else statement)

```
    $scope.pasteImage = function(eventPaste)
    {
        $scope.uploading = true;
        var promises = [];
        var items = (eventPaste.clipboardData  || eventPaste.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
        var blob = null;
            if (eventPaste.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[i].type.indexOf("image") == 0 || eventPaste.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[i] == 0)
            {
                blob = eventPaste.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
            }
            else
            {

                var file = new File("file:///home/oem/testabc/vembly/source/server/images/pregnant.png")
                console.log(file)
            }
        }
        console.log(eventPaste)
        console.log(blob)
        var files = [blob];


        uploadService.uploadMultiple(files)
}
```

so, my question is if its possible to transform that file (else statment) into a blob so i can use it in the uploadMultiple(files) funtction that i have.

Answer (score 1):

No.

It would be a huge security problem if any website could use JavaScript to read data from any file path on your system it happened to guess existed.

Comment: do you think it is possible to find any workaround for this? i basically need to copy a image from my computer to the website

Comment: Use a file input.